# Java exercise - family member

Tags: java

I write a program that gives the how type of family members.
For example: 0-3 age - baby, 3-12 - child, 12-31 , young etc. For this I used `if`

```
Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);
int age = klavye.nextInt();
age = klavye.nextInt(); 
age = klavye.nextInt();

int count = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0;

System.out.println("Enter the age of the family member : ");

if (age >= 0 && age <= 3);
    count++;

if(age >=4 && age <= 12);
    count1++;

if (age >= 13 && age <= 30);
    count2++;

if (age >= 31 && age <= 49);
    count3++;

if (age >=50 && age <= 120);
    count4++;

System.out.println(count+" "+ count3); // this to try to work "count"
```

When I write 3 times "49", I want show count3 = 3, but showed just 1.

Comment: you need a loop.

Comment: Aren't you only reading in an integer once? To read stuff multiple times you'll have to wrap it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code little bit:

1. Adedd Loop to take input multiple times. I have harcoded 3 in the loop.
2. Used `if..else if` construct, rather than `if`. This change is not mandatory, but a best practice.
3. Removed `;` from if statement

`Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);`

```
int count = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
System.out.println("Enter the age of the family member : ");
int age = klavye.nextInt();

if (age >= 0 && age <= 3)
    count++;
else if(age >=4 && age <= 12)
  count1++;
else if (age >= 13 && age <= 30)
  count2++;
else if (age >= 31 && age <= 49)
  count3++;
else if (age >=50 && age <= 120)
  count4++;
}
System.out.println(count+" "+ count3);
```

Comment: Thank you brother

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop and move the initialization of the variables outside of the loop.

```
int count = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0;
do {
    ...
} while(...);
```

Comment: Thank you brother